# richfaces modal panel with scroll scrolls the whole page

Tags: scroll, richfaces, modal-dialog, jsf-1.2

I am working with JSF 1.2 and Richfaces and I need to use a modal panel with scrollbars on it.
The behaviour is like this:
- if I scroll the popup using the mouse wheel, then the whole page (from behind) gets scrolled when the popup scrollbars reach the top or the end.
- if I scroll the popup by selecting the scrollbar, then the page is not scrolled, only the popup.

The bahaviour I want is that the page never gets scrolled when using the mouse wheel.
Any idea how can I achieve this?

Comment: Isn't that the default behavior in browsers? Also, As I've seen, the generated HTML for the modal panel is a div, so try to make a div with scroll bar working the way you need, and then just apply it to your modal panel.

Comment: the modal panel has inside a div with overflow: auto and fixed height which actually does the scrolling. And no, the default bahaviuor is not the one I want.

Comment: Try asking how to get that behavior with a div using html, javascript and css tags. The answer provided there can be applied into your modal panel AFAIK.

Comment: I will try to restrict the mouse scroll only to the popup using javascript. Thanks.